# MacOS bash: Python output script not always written to external file

Tags: python, bash, output, etl

**UPDATE:** I have a strong clue this is related to some buffering issue. If I use the command

`python -u ETL.py > data.log`

everything works fine when I run it form the Terminal. Nevertheless, I don't understand the origin of the problem, and when I automate the script execution using cron the data.log file is still empty.

---

I have a small ETL Python script that retrieves data from an API and loads it into a database. The script itself works fine, but I want to redirect its standard output to a log file to keep trace of what happens when I automate its execution.

Thus I run in Terminal:

`python ETL.py > data.log`

Here is the strange part: if I limit my ETL to just few tens of API requests, everything works fine, and I can see the output of the script in the data.log file. If I run the full ETL with around 1000 API requests, the data.log file is empty.

The script works fine in both cases, if I simply run

`python ETL.py`

I can see the output of my code directly in the terminal, and it works fine for 10 as well as for 1000 API requests.

**EDIT** (*it was probably not clear from my previous description*): the output I am writing in the log file does not come from API requests, it is simply some summary information such as:

> 745/750 successful requests
>
> List of retrieved features: ...
>
> Unable to retrieve the following data: ...

and so on.

Do you have any idea of why this is happening, and how to fix the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Try doing this `python ETL.py | tee data.log` and see if anything changes wrt either data.log or screen output.

Comment: No, the result on the data.log file is the same: it's fine with 10 API requests, but it's empty with 1000 requests. On the screen I see the expected standard output in both cases.

Comment: Is it possible that the 1000-line output somehow goes to `stderr` (standard error) instead of stdout? If you try it in terminal, without the log file, but hide stderr, with `python ETL.py 2>/dev/null` do you still get to see output?

Comment: It's not possible that `tee`'s output differs from the file it saves.

Comment: @JimDanner: yes, I still see the output. I also tried with ````python ETL.py > data.log 2>&1```` but the result does not change.

Comment: Could the file `data.log` somehow be overwritten by something that happens due to the interaction between your script and the database? What happens if you use a different filename (e.g. `testdata.log`), or put it in a different location?

Comment: Not sure I understand this... you have a script we can't see and you'd like us to tell you what's wrong with it?

Comment: @JimDanner: if I change the filename or the filepath, it works on the first run! But when I launch again the script (using a filename I already used before) I get an empty file again. May be I have somehow to tell bash to close the file connection before exiting?

Comment: @MarkSetchell: I thought the problem was with _bash_, since my script works fine when I run it without redirecting its output to a file. But if you think looking at the script itself can help I can share it.

Comment: You could see if bash has been told not to overwrite existing files, as described in [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/483124/323032). If that is the case, you could reverse that setting with `set +o noclobber` (with a `+` to turn the option off).